# Does ability score increases spell slots/spells per day/spells known?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

The Player's Handbook states that you can get "bonus spells" for certain ability scores, but does that mean more spell slots/spells per day, more spells known, or both?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is referencing the [Ability Scores and Spellcasters](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/theBasics.htm#abilitiesAndSpellcasters) section in the chapter about ability scores. In short, you get bonus spells per day, not spells known. Extra spells known tend to be rare and difficult to get, and will spell out explicitly that this is what you’re getting.

Comment: It is interesting to note that bonus spells (per day), due to high spellcasting key ability score, are not limited by level of spells known. This is due to the lack of explicit significance given to the dashes in a class's table of allotted spells per day. Therefore, if you have a way of knowing spells beyond your level (e.g., via runestaff) and have a high enough spellcasting key ability score...but this is theoretical optimization.

Comment: "In addition to having a high ability score, a spellcaster 
must be of high enough class level to be able to cast spells of a given spell level."-pg.7, Player's Handbook. ...this leads me to suspect otherwise.