# As a Sorcerer, can use I use a Page of Knowledge to use Spell Slots granted by my Charisma bonus, even if they're higher level then otherwise?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, sorcerer

The [Sorcerer](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/) description has this to say:

> A sorcerer casts arcane spells drawn primarily from the
> sorcerer/wizard spell list. She can cast any spell she knows without
> preparing it ahead of time. To learn or cast a spell, a sorcerer must
> have a Charisma score equal to at least 10 + the spell level.
>
> ...
>
> She
> can cast any spell she knows at any time, assuming she has not yet
> used up her spells per day for that spell level.

As a Sorcerer, you get bonus spells based on Charisma. In my case, I rolled an 18 at the start, invested points at levels 4 and 8, got 2 point for being an Ifrit(racial bonus), and I'm wearing a [Headband of Alluring Charisma (+4)](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/h-l/headband-of-alluring-charisma/). This gives me a Charisma stat of 26.

The [Table of bonus spells](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/ability-scores#TOC-Table:-Ability-Modifiers-and-Bonus-Spells) shows I get, among others, a Level 7 and a level 8 spell slot.

However, I recently obtained Craft Wondrous Item, which lets me make [Page of Spell Knowledge](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/m-p/page-of-spell-knowledge).

Lets's say I craft a Page of [Limited Wish](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/l/limited-wish/), a Level 7 spell. Despite not knowing it, I can do that by taking a +5 on the DC, and taking 10 on the spellcraft Crafting check.

Would this allow me to cast Limited Wish? I have a spell slot of the appropriate level (higher, even), and I have the page to make the spell "known" to me.

While the answer is the same, this question is different from [this one](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/36325/48073) because that one is about metamagic, and this one is about Page of Spell Knowledge. There will be few if any search queries turning up both questions (and that one certainly didn't show up in the "similar questions" list when I asked this one).

Comment: Please note: I'm aware that from a balance perspective a GM might decide to forbid it anyway. I might if I were running the campaign.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### No, you don't get bonus spells of a level you can't normally cast

Next to the table of ability modifiers and bonus spells you've linked is the important caveat:

> In addition to having a high ability score, a spellcaster must be of a high enough class level to be able to cast spells of a given spell level.

Your charisma might be high enough that you would get a bonus 7th level spell, but you don't get that benefit until your class level is high enough to grant access to 7th level spells normally.

Some might argue that the rules text appears ambiguous, but this is explicitly clarified in the [Pathfinder FAQ](https://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9o91):

> **Bonus Spells from a High Ability Score: Can I use these even if my spellcasting class level isn't high enough to give me access to those spell levels?**
>
> No. You only get the bonus spells if your class level grants you access to those spell levels. You can't even use them for lower-level spells. [...]
>
> Basically, ignore the columns for higher-level spells on table 1–3: Ability Modifiers and Bonus Spells until your class grants you access to those spell levels.

This is also backed up by inference from some other rules text; for instance, the Paladin's Spells feature states:

> When Table: Paladin indicates that the paladin gets 0 spells per day of a given spell level, she gains only the bonus spells she would be entitled to based on her Charisma score for that spell level.

If the paladin already had those bonus spells, it would not make sense to say that they "gain" them at a later level.

Comment: I hadn't read that line that way. I can see where you're coming from. But on the other hand, my class doesn't say I can't cast Level 7 spells - it merely doesn't give me the tools to do so. I wish they'd been a bit more explicit here. Anyway, upvote. I'll accept in a few days unless there's a far more convincing answer.

Comment: @Gloweye I think its more expressly stated somewhere, but this ruling is correct. Until the class gives you a 0+ to a spell level, you cant use spell slots of that level.

Comment: @Carcer may want to include [this FAQ](https://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9o91) which is a bit more explicit.

Comment: @willuwontu done, but I do think this should probably be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Whelp, that FAQ seals it imo. Shame.

Comment: @Gloweye It is perhaps worth observing that some classes like Paladin have some levels where their class grants "0" spell slots and they can only use their bonus slots for those levels. That '0' is different to '--' is a strong clue that you need to have a numerical number of spell slots from your class to benefit from bonus slots.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that about an hour after I asked the question, once in bed. Bard would be a better example, as they're both Arcane. I thought about editing it in, but I think that doesn't matter anymore with the FAQ quote. Regardless, it'll work in my sessions, since the GM already let me use the higher slots for metamagic. That is, if I can find the gold to craft them....