# Can i cast a spell using a higher-level spell slot with stats bonus slot?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e

I have a lvl 8 wizard, with 24INT.

Now, the wizards table grants me access only to level 4 spells, with 2 slots.

However, 24INT gives me 2 further bonus slots, one in 5 level and one in 6th respectively.

My question is, can i use these bonus slots to cast spells at higher level?

Comment: Unfortunately, the duplicate notice can’t link to a precise answer, which is unfortunate because the accepted answer to the duplicate question only covers Pathfinder and not both 3.5e and Pathfinder as the question expects. Nonetheless, it is the place for this question in both systems, and [my answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/36327/4563), for example, covers the relevant rules in both. The answer is “no.”